# RepositoryNotFoundError while using llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin

Tags: llama

I am using colab to interact with CSV.

```
# Load the locally downloaded model
def load_llm():
    llm = CTransformers(
        model = "llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin",
        model_type="llama",
        max_new_tokens = 512,
        temperature = 0.5
    )
    return llm


uploaded_file = '/content/2019.csv'
loader = CSVLoader(file_path=uploaded_file, encoding="utf-8", csv_args={'delimiter': ','})
data = loader.load()

# Initialize embeddings and vector store
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name='sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2', model_kwargs={'device': 'cpu'})
db = FAISS.from_documents(data, embeddings)
llm = load_llm()
chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm=llm, retriever=db.as_retriever())


    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    RepositoryNotFoundError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_errors.py in hf_raise_for_status(response, endpoint_name)
        291                 " make sure you are authenticated."
        292             )
    --> 293             raise RepositoryNotFoundError(message, response) from e
        294 
        295         elif response.status_code == 400:
    
    RepositoryNotFoundError: 401 Client Error. (Request ID: Root=1-64e367a0-03a4565e09b69d8b0d3624fb;5108be96-cf03-475c-a68f-c6481f96b567)

Repository Not Found for url: https://huggingface.co/api/models/llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin/revision/main.
Please make sure you specified the correct `repo_id` and `repo_type`.
If you are trying to access a private or gated repo, make sure you are authenticated.
Invalid username or password.
```

https://huggingface.co/api/models/llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin/revision/main is not found and returning 404 so i am getting this error. what is the resolution to get this model in colab- any suggestion would be really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this way the download of the model is carried out without problem.

```py
from huggingface_hub import hf_hub_download

# https://huggingface.co/docs/huggingface_hub/v0.16.3/en/package_reference/file_download#huggingface_hub.hf_hub_download
hf_hub_download(
    repo_id="TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GGML",
    filename="llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin",
    local_dir="./models"
)
```

Or with [ctransformers](https://github.com/marella/ctransformers), you can load from Hugging Face Hub directly and specify a model file (.bin or .gguf files) using:

```py
from ctransformers import AutoModelForCausalLM

llm = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GGML", model_file="llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin")
```